# Can we interchange the order of limit and derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Can you explain with an example that $$\frac{d}{dx} \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{d}{dx} f_n(x)$$
Is not true in general?

Comment: @Heepo Your edit distorted the question. Sorry about accepting it. I carelessly thought that you simply TeXified it, but you had removed the subscripts $n$ from the functions and introduced some strange $x\to a$ making one of the limits meaningless. If you don't understand basic analysis, just don't try and guess.

Comment: Anyway, you can change the order of these two limiting processes if $f_n(x)$ converges at one point  to $f(x)$ and the sequence $f_n'(x)$ converges to $f'(x)$ uniformly in a bounded interval.

Answer (score 2):

$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)$.

- Observe that for any $x$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=0$.  We can see this since $0\leq\left|\frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n}$ and applying the squeeze theorem.
- Since $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=0$ is a constant function, its derivative is $0$ everywhere.
- Observe that at $f'_n(x)=\cos(nx)$.  Therefore, for all $n$, $f'_n(0)=\cos(0)=1$.

Therefore, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}(0)=0.$$
On the other hand, 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( f_n'(0)\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1)=1.
$$
Therefore, the derivative of the limit and the limit of the derivatives do not agree at $x=0$.

Comment: The poster may be asking for an intuitive explanation rather than just an example, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac {x^{n}} n$, $f(x)=0$. Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ but $f_n'(1) \to 1$ so $lim f_n'(1)=1\neq 0=\frac d { dx} f(x)$. .

Comment: Sir, is there any condition on function as well...is it must be continuous?

Comment: @NaseemAkhtar In my example $f_n,f_n'$, $f$ and $f'$ are all continuous.

Comment: @NaseemAkhtar $f_n(1)=\frac  1 n \to 0$.

Comment: So now can i say that if the series fn(x) converging pointwise to f is continuous then the order of limit and derivative can be changed?

Comment: @NaseemAkhtar I gave an example to show that you cannot interchange the order. In fact there are no known simple conditions on $f_n$ and $f$ under which $\lim f_n'(x)=\frac d  {dx} \lim f_n(x)$ without bringing in analyticity.